# Punctuation order

Tags: punctuation, quotation-marks, question-marks

Where do you place punctuation when quoting a question? Also in general. I’m not sure whether to place the quotation mark before or after the punctuation mark.

-“How can a young man cleanse his ways”?

Or

-“How can a young man cleanse his ways?”

Comment: For your information, http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/ is where I always go for rules on punctuation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> “How can a young man cleanse his ways?”

Answer (score 1):

The question mark goes outside the quotation mark unless it is part of the quoted material. So, in this case, the question mark goes inside. Consider these two:

> "How can a young man cleanse his ways?" he asked.
>   Did he say "A young man can cleanse his ways"?